# Pymongo has been pip installed, but can't be imported

Tags: python-3.x, import, pymongo, libraries

I am trying to run a Flask webapp on my computer but I have some issues when importing pymongo library. It has been downloaded but it can't be imported:

```
(sce_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Learning\scentmate_rec\webapp>python -m pip3 install pymongo
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Learning\scentmate_rec\scraper\sce_env\Scripts\python.exe: No module named pip3

(sce_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Learning\scentmate_rec\webapp>python -m pip install pymongo
Requirement already satisfied: pymongo in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\learning\scentmate_rec\scraper\sce_env\lib\site-packages (3.11.1)

(sce_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Learning\scentmate_rec\webapp>python app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 137, in <module>
    client = pymongo.MongoClient(
NameError: name 'pymongo' is not defined
```

Weird thing is that it perfectly works in another of my projects

So how can I make the app find the pymongo library?

Answer (score 0):

A `NameError` comes when the module has not been imported first. You need to import the module first. Add

```
import pymongo
```

at the top of your file (or some other appropriate location).

If a module is not installed and you try to import it, you would get a `ModuleNotFoundError`, such as

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymongo'
```